# Random proportion of subset

Tags: probability

Say I have a set of N elements, where N is very large and M ⊆ N.  If I randomly pick X% of elements in N, can I assume that I will end up choosing the same X% proportion of the total number of elements in M as well?  What's the correct way to think about this?

Comment: Try putting real numbers. Say N = 100, M = 1, and X = 1. So choosing X% of the elements means just one element. Do you think that by randomly picking a number between 1 and 100, you will also pick 1% of $\{1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes. That follows from the meaning of "random".

If $M$ itself is large (even if it's only a small part of $N$) then you will choose approximately $X\%$ of it. There are ways to predict how accurate that approximation is likely to be.

If $M$ is small the answer can't be "yes". As @MTurgeon comments, if $M$ has just one element then you have either picked it or not, but can't pick $X\%$ of it (unless $X$ is $0$ or $2$). You will pick that one element $X\%$ of the time.